# reading desired data from file but saving the whole file data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have made a GUI using swing, i read data from a text file to the jtable,
the text file has 6 columns and 5 rows,the 3 row has values 0,0.0,0,0,0,0.so i want to display 
values in the JTable till it encounters 0.but to save the full text file while saving which means values of 5 rows.here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Bb extends JFrame
{
 private JTable table;
 private DefaultTableModel model;

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public Bb()
 {
      String aLine ;
      Vector columnNames = new Vector();
      Vector data = new Vector();

      try
      {
           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("Bbb.txt");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));



           StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");

           while( st1.hasMoreTokens())
           {
                columnNames.addElement(st1.nextToken());
           }



           while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null )
           {
                StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(aLine, " ");
                Vector row = new Vector();

                while(st2.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                     row.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                }
                  data.addElement( row );
           }
           br.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }


      model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
      table = new JTable(model);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
      getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );


      JButton button2 = new JButton( "SAVE TABLE" );
      buttonPanel.add( button2 );
      button2.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
      {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {


                   if  ( table.isEditing() )
                {
                     int row = table.getEditingRow();
                     int col = table.getEditingColumn();
                     table.getCellEditor(row, col).stopCellEditing();
                }

                int rows = table.getRowCount();
                int columns = table.getColumnCount();


                try { 

StringBuffer Con = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++)
  {
        for  (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++)
     {

       Object Value = table.getValueAt(i, j);
       Con.append(" ");
           Con.append(Value);
         }
   Con.append("\r\n");
   }

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("cc.txt"));
fileWriter.write(Con.toString());
    fileWriter.flush();
fileWriter.close();  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }  
           }
      });



 }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      Bb frame = new Bb();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

and the text file:

```
1 2 6 0.002 0.00 2
2 5 5 0.005 0.02 4
0 0 0 0.000 0.00 0
4 8 9 0.089 0.88 7
5 5 4 0.654 0.87 9
```

Comment: What is your problem / question?

Comment: @Rudy dev Vector class is obsolete and nobody uses that anymore.

Comment: @KickButtowski, the `DefaultTableModel` class still does and Rudy is using the data from his file to populate the `DefaultTableModel` to be used with the `JTable`.

Comment: @camickr oh K I understand what he wants to do but if he wants all of first file to be saved in second file why he does not copy them from first file to second file? why he copied from JTable to second file? Could you please tell me if I am thinking right ?

Comment: @camickr I posted my answer can you tell me what you think?

Comment: @Rudy dev I posted my answer lemme know it helps

Comment: @KickButtowski, I don't understand the question so I have no idea if the answer is appropriate.

Comment: the person wants to stop populating jtabel after any row which has zero but I don't get why op wants to populate second file by using jtable content

Comment: @KickButtowski i want to display the contents of my text file in jtable till it encounters 0,user can edit the values in jtable and then save the whole data of the text file in another file and the values after 0 will remain unchanged.

Comment: so my answer didn't help?

Comment: @Rudydev what do u mean till encounter 0?

Comment: Thank you@Kick Buttowski your code has helped me.but i want the portion of data displayed
in jtable user can edit and the edited values along with the remaining data in the text file
to be saved to another file.

Comment: @Rudydev did you see my update? did it help you? plz lemme know

Comment: Thank you so very much@Kick Buttowski the code is showing as expected but their is a problem.
In jtable it shows the accurate result but when we save it,the first line when it encounters 0 is
getting discarded from the saved file and the rest shows perfectly fine.can u help with that

Comment: Can u please @Kick Buttowski help me with the problem of the first line getting discarded when it encounters 0 in the saved file.

Comment: @Rudydev email me pazpaz22@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to understand what you want

For first part that you just wanted to show your data in your `JTable` till you encounter `0`

**code:**

```
 while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] sp = aLine.split(" ");
            if (sp[0].equals("0")) {
                break;
            }
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(aLine, " ");
            Vector row = new Vector();

            while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {

                String s = st2.nextToken();
                row.addElement(s);
            }

            data.addElement(row);
        }
```

**Explanation:** when you read each line, split it, so if the first element of each splitted line is zero, you come out of the loop and do not show any other values inside the loop.

For saving all your data from first file to second file, you should copy them from first file to second file because your `JTable` will not have enough info to help your purpose in this matter.

Note: **I do not understand why you want to do this** but you can accomplish that in following way

**Code:**

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (table.isEditing()) {
                int row = table.getEditingRow();
                int col = table.getEditingColumn();

                table.getCellEditor(row, col).stopCellEditing();
            }

            int rows = table.getRowCount();
            int columns = table.getColumnCount();

            try {
                String st = "";
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\J Urguby"
                        + "\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bb\\src\\bb\\Bbb.txt");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(fin).useDelimiter("\\A");
                while (input.hasNext()) {
                    st = input.next();
                    System.out.println("st is " + st);
                }

                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\J Urguby"
                        + "\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bb\\src\\bb\\cc.txt"));
                fileWriter.write(st);
                fileWriter.flush();
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

**Explanation**: you read the whole file with Scanner trick and write it down into a second file. 
Source: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner.html

Based on what the OP requested

Code:

```
 public Bb() {
        String aLine;
        Vector columnNames = new Vector();
        Vector data = new Vector();
        boolean found = false;
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        /*Using try catch block with resources Java 7 
          Read about it
        */
        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\8888"
                + "\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bb\\src\\bb\\Bbb.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin))) {

            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");
            //the first line of the txt file fill colum names
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String s = st1.nextToken();
                columnNames.addElement(s);
            }

            while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] sp = aLine.split(" ");
                if (sp[0].equals("0") && !found) {
                    found = true;
                } else if (found) {
                    temp.append(aLine).append("\r\n");
                } else if (!sp[0].equals("0") && !found) {
                    StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(aLine, " ");
                    Vector row = new Vector();
                    while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String s = st2.nextToken();
                        row.addElement(s);
                    }
                    data.addElement(row);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton button2 = new JButton("SAVE TABLE");
        buttonPanel.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (table.isEditing()) {
                    int row = table.getEditingRow();
                    int col = table.getEditingColumn();

                    table.getCellEditor(row, col).stopCellEditing();
                }

                int rows = table.getRowCount();
                int columns = table.getColumnCount();

                try {
                    StringBuilder con = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            Object Value = table.getValueAt(i, j);
                            con.append(" ");
                            con.append(Value);
                        }
                        con.append("\r\n");
                    }

                    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\8888"
                            + "\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Bb\\src\\bb\\cc.txt"))) {
                        fileWriter.write(con.append(temp).toString());
                        fileWriter.flush();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

**My code just works if you have row includes zeros. if you want to make it better to cover up all conditions, I am sure you can follow my plan.**

Sample to get rid of all zeros like

```
1 1 1
0 0 0
0 0 0
1 1 1
```

Code:

```
        String s = "xxxooooooxxx";
        String[] sp = s.split("");
        boolean xFlag = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
            if (sp[i].equals("x") && !xFlag) {
                System.out.print("x");
            } else if (sp[i].equals("o")) {
                xFlag = true;
            } else if (sp[i].equals("x") && xFlag) {
                System.out.print("X");
            }
        }
```

output:

```
xxxXXX
```